# Google Analytics api Params for custom channel grouping

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I created a custom channel grouping to tag my traffic from referral and email with a specific UTM parameter now the data is collecting and in GA acquisition > Channel I am able to choose my custom channel group as primary dimension for reporting and it’s looking exactly I want it.

Now I need to pull the report for these custom channel grouping using reporting api. However when I do try and add channel group to dimension the standard channel grouping is returned. I tried adding in filters as well.

Please not that the custom channel grouping is based on complex reflex patterns and multitude of combinations, so implementing it in api will not be possible. Is there any way of telling GA API that I need my custom channel
Grouping and not it’s default one?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `custom channel grouping` is **not** still supported with Google Analytics API.